# FullCalender5 how to use setextendedproperty to display non standard attributes

Tags: javascript

I cannt use json as input as it doesnt fit into our requirement. I have a need to pass the Fields using events array only.

Can some please let me know how to add Non Standard attributes to events array? can you please show by example code which i can add to my below given code?

below is my js file to load data into events array, title , start and end are printing but QuantityOrdered  is not printed on the fullcalender

```
function renderData(self,data)  {
    self = this;
    this.events = [];
    data.forEach(element => {
        const obj ={};
    
        obj.title = element.TABLE_LITM.value,
        obj.start = new Date(element.TABLE_DRQJ.value),
        obj.end= new Date(element.TABLE_STRT.value),
        obj.QuantityOrdered = element.TABLE_UORG.value,
        events.push(obj);               
    });   
                 
    this.calendar = $ ('#calendar').fullCalendar(
    {    
    editable: true,
    weekends : false,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper:true,  
    timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',
    displayEventTime: false,
    header:{
        left : 'prev,next,today',
        center : 'title',
        right : 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },   
    events:  events,
});
```

Comment: I have tried below as well:     Tried to load the Non Standard fields using extended props still it doesnt work                                                
        extendedProps.QuantityOrdered = element.TABLE_UORG.value,
        extendedProps.QuantityCompleted = element.TABLE_SOQS.value,
        obj.extendedProps = extendedProps,
        events.push(obj);

Comment: Please put this comment in the answer itself by editing it instead of adding it as a comment

Answer (score 1):

You can add non-standard fields to a FullCalendar event in both ways you mentioned:

```
var events = [];
concerts.forEach(concert => {
    events.push({
        title: concert.name,
        start: concert.startTime,
        end: concert.endTime,
        extendedProps: {
            price: concert.price
        },
        venue: concert.venue
    })
});
```

In the code above, we have `price` inside `extendedProps` and `venue` in the object root.

During event parsing, `venue` will be moved to inside `extendedProps`. Then, you can access both fields in an [event render hook](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks) like `eventDidMount`, for example:

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  events: events,
  eventDidMount: function(info) {
    console.log(info.event.extendedProps.price);
    //will print 100
    console.log(info.event.extendedProps.venue);
    //will print "Mercedes-Benz Arena"
  }
});
```